# jQuery <select> with 3 steps needed correct

Tags: jquery

Need update this script http://jsfiddle.net/Nazaret2005/e8vBf/ to work with 3 steps of select. now work with 2 only... needed like

```
- step 1      -step 2      -step 3
  -1  ------>  -1  ------>  -1
  -2           -2           -2
  -3           -3           -3
```

thanks

Comment: You didn't do any code to appear last list

Comment: I do not know how, so please help to make it

Comment: I can show a sample method, hope you can work on it

Comment: show me, maybe its will help me. thanks

Comment: @ser3436980 please have a look the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#Main').change(function () {
    var val = $('#Main').val();
    $('.Subselect').hide();
    if (val) {
        $('#Next' + val).show();
    }
});
$('.Subselect').change(function () {
    var subSel = $(this).val();
    $(".lastSel").hide();
    $("#"+subSel).show();
});
```

with this method You can have as much dropdown list you want :)

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/e8vBf/11/

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/e8vBf/3/

```
$('#NextUSA').change(function () {
    var val = $('#NextUSA').val();
    $('#LosAngeles').hide();
    if (val == "Los Angeles") {
        $('#LosAngeles').show();

    }
});
```

Comment: if i chooise Whashington its show me same <select id="LosAngeles" class="Subselect">... :-/

Comment: see the updated -- (didnt bother putting it in fiddle)

Comment: i update little your code and now work good for me. thanks http://jsfiddle.net/Nazaret2005/e8vBf/8/

Answer (score 2):

do like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Main').change(function () {
        var val = $('#Main').val();
        $('.Subselect').hide();
        if (val) {

            $('#Next' + val).show();

        }
    });

    $('select.Subselect').change(function(){

    var id = this.id;
    var val = $(this).val();


      $('select.Subselect#'+val).show();

    });
});
```

check here: http://jsfiddle.net/e8vBf/4/